# Chrome: Issue with changing select menu content dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, select, dynamic

When a user clicks on a select menu, I build the  values dynamically in Javascript, and then call the jquery .html function on the select element. I can see the dynamic options in Firefox, but  in Chrome and Safari, the select menu shows nothing. The options only show up if I close the menu and open it again. Anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

```
var selectionDiv = $('#someSelectElement');
var newHtml = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   newHtml += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
}
selectionDiv.html(newHtml);
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: What do you mean with "opens"?

Comment: So this is fired on a `click` event? If so, why are you waiting until they click to build the `options`? I could see how the result would be vary between browsers.

Comment: Sorry - I mean "clicks" a select menu.

Comment: I need to build the options when they click the select menu because I have a lot of select menus on my page (each one does something different), and I only want to do something (potentially expensive) ONLY if the user is interested in that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is up to the browser implementation as to whether the menu is displayed before or after the click handler finishes. As such, you could get (and apparently are getting) different results between browsers.

I guess some browsers prefer to display the menu immediately so there's no lag, at the expense of any modification to the `options` not having a chance to take place.

Best solution may be to simply not try to modify the content on a `click` event. If you need this functionality, perhaps you could use `mouseover` instead.

If you use `mouseover` then you could use [jQuery's `.one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/), so it only runs once.

```
$('#someSelectElement').one('mouseover', function() {

    var newHtml = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       newHtml += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
    }
    $(this).html(newHtml);

});
```

Comment: Nice - I didn't think about doing that on a mouseover. Building the options menu worked nicely in Chrome on the mouseover event.

Comment: Is the function that executes on mouseover guaranteed to finish execution before the user clicks?  What if it's an expensive function that takes like a second to return, but the user immediately clicks after mousing over.  Then would the menu that pops up have the options not loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to wrap your code in ready event

```
$(function(){
  var selectionDiv = $('#someSelectElement');
  var newHtml = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
     newHtml += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
  }
  selectionDiv.html(newHtml);
});
```

You may try this too:

```
$(function(){
  var selectionDiv = $('#someSelectElement');
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
     selectionDiv.html(selectionDiv.html() + "<option>" + i + "</option>");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately both methods don't work.